# Discord Bot Trigger on Webhook Received

Tags: discord, bots, webhooks

I am trying to pipe notifications from various online services into a Discord server using Webhooks. The problem is, discord doesn't render the message that is received by a webhook the way I need. It omits some information that I would like to display.

**Is it possible to receive the raw JSON information from a webhook when it arrives, then process it and post into a channel?**

My thinking was: I can create a new bot, then subscribe to some kind of *webhook_message_received* event and process it the way I want. Turns out, there's no such event (or I don't know where to look).

There's not much information online, so I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Are you using discord.js? If so you could just spin up an express server inside your bot and export request data to a channel

Comment: Yes, I can use `discord.js`, but I don't see how I can receive webhook data programmatically.

Comment: a webhook is just a fancy term for a get request to a specific destination. For example, when you make a "webhook" with discord you're just making a route that can have a get request made on it to post messages. So you could tell github for example to use http://yourdomainorip:3000/sadfaskdhfjahljh3khkhlkjashfh/ as the url to perform the get request on. I hope this is a good explanation, otherwise I can try to go into more detail

Comment: When theoretically I can spin up my own GET listener, and then redirect all requests with raw data to my discord bot, I prefer using 'native webhook' from Discord UI, as it, as far as I know, provides authorization for the communication channel. If I spin up my own endpoint, I don't want to think about the authorization.

Comment: That's fair, but then at that point, you can't intercept the webhook if you made it through the channel UI. You need to use the 0auth2 layout with your discord bot with the webhook.incoming scope.

Comment: @Kwright02 so from your perspective, the only way to go is to create my own endpoint, and then teach it how to authenticate with my discord bot via Oauth?

Comment: If this express server is hosted inside the bot, what would be the URL to access it?

Comment: whatever you set it to. Like if you make it listen on port 3000 it would still just be localhost:3000, but you could for example make it listen for a route that you use as the webhook, then perform bot code

Comment: @Kwright02 what I mean is what will be the external url? I.e. I need to give to my application an endpoint address where it will send the webhook data.

Comment: You make it whatever you want. You just make the route in express and make sure your port is forwarded if you need that.